# How to Pass Data to a Parent Component Without Firing Render Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to create a length unit converter app in React to practice, but I have a problem with managing states.

In my **App** component, I have the following components

1. **Value** which contains the input field where the user can type in the number they want to convert.
2. **ConversionType** which contains the from and to unit types, but I also have the convert button set up here as well because of how I want my UI structured.
3. **Result** which displays the result of the conversion.

The problem I am having though is: when the state of the input field in the **Value** component updates, I have to pass its value to the **App** component upwards and update the **App** component state with that value so I can then pass it down to the **Result** component for display, but the App component keeps rendering each time I type into the input field thus re-rendering the **Result** component as well and creating this real-time conversion effect.

I do not want this to happen, I only want to re-render the  **Result** when the convert button is clicked in the **ConversionType** component.

So my question is, how do I send state from **Value** to **App** and Without re-rendering **App** every time?

Sorry if I was not explicit enough. I didn't really know how to pose the question.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a [mcve] as a snippet in the question?  That would make it easier to provide you with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking updating a parent component shouldn't re-render all children. React only updates components whose props or internal state have updated.

If you only want Result to be updated when you click then you need to (1) add a result state to the App component (2) pass that to the props of Result and (3) only update that value once ConversionType click event is fired.

Alternatively, you might want to look at some kind of state managment solution if your app is big enough. I'm a fan of https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy it means you don't need to keep passing stuff around manually, but rather you update the central store and the results just filter down automatically.